# Prevent NSDocument saving in temporary dictionary

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, filesystems, sandbox

I have an app with subclass of NSDocument that has overridden method `writeToURL:(NSURL *) ofType:(NSString *) error:(NSError **)` which saves data at given `NSURL` location, but also can save additional file (with appended `.my2ext`) with debug information. Previously it worked well (I created the app several years ago), but now I see that instead of user selected location the method gets some temporary directory:

> file:///var/folders/yv/gwf3_hjs0ps7sb3psh3d0w3m0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/(A%20Document%20Being%20Saved%20By%20MyApp%202)/myfilename.myext

Then, as I understand, the framework relocates the main file (at given url), but the additional file gets lost. So, can I somehow obtain the user selected path to save directly into it? Or prevent using temp directories at all?

I've already turned off the SandBox mode, but this didn't help. I also know that I can use ["File Package"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/AdvancedTopics/AdvancedTopics.html) approach, but my app is created for a few people only, so, there is not interest in good production approach, only in simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to google any possible solution, but found nothing helpful or just related. Even the documentation says nothing about using temporary directories! So, I decided to override different NSDocument methods. After several experiments I almost lost hope, but then I found that the method
[saveToURL: ofType: forSaveOperation: delegate: didSaveSelector: contextInfo:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocument/1515148-savetourl) provides real, user selected location. And this finally solved the problem.